# How to print the order of hierarchical clustering in R?

Tags: r, dendrogram, hclust

Using the following matrix of distances between 6 Italian cities:

```
0   662 877 255 412 996
662 0   295 468 268 400
877 295 0   754 564 138
255 468 754 0   219 869
412 268 564 219 0   669
996 400 138 869 669 0
```

Will R output the order of which it clustered them in:
For example, single-linkage would tell you:

```
City 3 and City 6, followed by
City 4 and City 5, followed by
City 1 to City 4 and City 5, finally City 2 to City 3 and City 6.
```

It is important that I get a numeric output rather than read it off a dendrogram.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know a complete solution for your problem but maybe you could use the `merge` value returned by `hclust`.

From `?hclust`:

> merge: an n-1 by 2 matrix.  Row i of ‘merge’ describes the merging
>          of clusters at step i of the clustering.  If an element j in
>          the row is negative, then observation -j was merged at this
>          stage.  If j is positive then the merge was with the cluster
>          formed at the (earlier) stage j of the algorithm.  Thus
>          negative entries in ‘merge’ indicate agglomerations of
>          singletons, and positive entries indicate agglomerations of
>          non-singletons.

Your example:

```
d <- as.dist(read.table(textConnection("
0   662 877 255 412 996
662 0   295 468 268 400
877 295 0   754 564 138
255 468 754 0   219 869
412 268 564 219 0   669
996 400 138 869 669 0")))

hc <- hclust(d, method="single")

plot(hc)
```

[image: hcplot]

```
hc$merge

#     [,1] [,2]  # from bottom up
#[1,]   -3   -6  # City 3 and 6
#[2,]   -4   -5  # City 4 and 5
#[3,]   -1    2  # join City 1 and City 4/5
#[4,]   -2    3  # join City 2 and City 1/4/5
#[5,]    1    4  # join City 3/6 and City 1/2/4/5
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I need it so I can decide which clusters were grouped at the same time. I know cutree will tell you which elements are in each cluster, however, if several clusters join at the same height it will 'randomly' split this cluster up.